# LOAD DATA INFILE executed but zero row effected

Tags: php, mysql, excel, csv

I added two additional columns in my csv file which contain some Excel formula because I needed to download the MySQL data as an excel file in which those formulas will react.

But after adding these two additional columns the data is not getting inserted into the table.

My code is:

```
$a = file('/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/upload/data.csv');// get array of lines
$new = '';
$i=1;
//$formula1 = "=IF(A$i>=40,2,IF(A$i=20,1))";
foreach($a as $line){
    $line = trim($line);// remove end of line
    $line .="|=IF(A$i>=40,2,IF(A$i=20,1))"."|=IF(COUNTIF(\$B:\$B,B".$i.")=1,1,C".$i."/COUNTIF(\$B:\$B,B".$i."))";// append new column
    $new .= $line.PHP_EOL;//append end of line
    $i++;
}
$outputfile = file_put_contents('/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/upload/data.csv', $new);// overwrite the same file with new data


$termit = "|";
$encls = "'\"'";
$lyn = "'\r\n'";

$cvsfile = "'/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/upload/data.csv'";

$dalete = mysql_query("delete FROM upload_excel_file");
$data_upload = mysql_query ("LOAD DATA INFILE $cvsfile INTO TABLE $cvsfile FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' ENCLOSED BY $encls LINES TERMINATED BY $lyn IGNORE 1 LINES;");
```

Comment: mysql is not excel those formulas will just show as raw text

Comment: i have no issue if its show as raw text but atleast show currently i not getting any data. my table is empty after running this code.

Comment: you are missing the comma separators for the new lines

Comment: can you please make correction in my code??? then i would easily get the point and my mistake.

Comment: just add the missing commas

Comment: $line .="|=IF(A$i>=40,2,IF(A$i=20,1))"."|=IF(COUNTIF(\$B:\$B,B".$i.")=1,1,C".$i."/COUNTIF(\$B:\$B,B".$i."))";// append new column

you mean in this line?